# get last children in multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I need a little help, i have multi array categories, i need to get last children in in each array

```
0=>array(
   "categoryName"=>"category1",
   "categorySlug"=>"categorys1",
   "categoryNested"=>array(
        0=>array(
           "categoryName"=>"category2",
           "categorySlug"=>"categorys2",
           "categoryNested"=>array(
               0=>array(
                  "categoryName"=>"category3",
                  "categorySlug"=>"categorys3",
               )
            )
       )   

),
1=>array(
   "categoryName"=>"category4",
   "categorySlug"=>"categorys4",
   "categoryNested"=>array()   
),
```

**example:**

need to get category3(categoryName),category4(categoryName), array is multidimensional

Comment: so only categoryName and its value?

Comment: The last how many children?

Comment: yes, just categoryName

Comment: get finite children, see example

Comment: Can you show us the expected result? I then will modify my answer :)

Comment: need to get result (in example above) "categoryName"=>"category3","categoryName"=>"category4",

Comment: @JoeRess You can't have to elements with the same key in an array I think you need `array("category3", "category4")`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<?php
$a = array(0=>array(
   "categoryName"=>"category1",
   "categorySlug"=>"categorys1",
   "categoryNested"=>array(
        "categoryName"=>"category2",
        "categorySlug"=>"categorys2",
        "categoryNested"=>array(
           "categoryName"=>"category3",
           "categorySlug"=>"categorys3",
        )
    )   

),
1=>array(
   "categoryName"=>"category4",
   "categorySlug"=>"categorys4",
   "categoryNested"=>array()   
));

$cats = array();
foreach ($a as $cat){
    while (isset($cat["categoryNested"]) && count($cat["categoryNested"])){
        $cat = $cat["categoryNested"];
    }
    $cats[] =  $cat["categoryName"];
}
print_r($cats);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using a anonymous function:

```
$lastElements = array();

$findLastElements = function ($array) use (&$lastElements, &$findLastElements) { //create anonymous function

    foreach($array as $key => $value) { //loop trough the array
        if (isset($value['categoryNested']) && !empty($value['categoryNested'])) {
            call_user_func($findLastElements, $value); 
        } elseif(isset($value['categoryName'])) {
            array_push($lastElements, $value['categoryName']);
        }
    }            
};

$findLastElements($array); //call the function

print_r($lastElements); //print the result
```

Comment: + need consider indexes

Comment: your solution is interesting, but how i can apply it using OOP ?

Comment: Why don't you create a public function with this anonymous function inside, or a static function that recalls itself ?

Comment: Joe, what about a chat?